# Qmake incorrect output directory

Tags: qt, directory, qmake

When I try to generate a makefile with qmake in a sub-directory, the makefile is generated in a wrong directory.

Here is my QmakeTest.pro, the main.cpp is a simple hello world code :

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

When I run qmake:

```sh
qmake -makefile -o build/makefile
qmake -makefile -o build/makefile
```

The first time, the folder *build/* is created and the makefile is created in the right directory, the second time(and each time if *build/* already exist), the makefile is generated in the folder *build/build/* (a subfolder *build* inside the first one).

Why does qmake create a second subdirectory if the subdirectory *build/* already exist ?

For info: `qmake --version`

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.3.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Edit: The bug seems to be fixed with the QMake provided with qt 5.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 QMAKE_MAKEFILE += build/makefile
```

in your project file to create the makefile